# How to prevent the common layout/shell component to be destroyed when lazy loading a module?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-routing

Consider the following two modules -

- Public module - contains Home, about, etc components
- Private module - contains Profile, Settings, etc components

All these components use a shared shell/layout `MainShellComponent` which is configured in `app-routing.module` as -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainShellComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
            { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent },
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```

I wanted to configure the Private module to lazy load. So I changed the code in `app-routing.module` -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainShellComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }         
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'user',
        component: MainShellComponent,
        loadChildren: './private/private.module#PrivateModule'
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

and in `private-routing.module` -

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
    { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent }
];
```

Now the Private module is loading lazily but the `MainShellComponent` is being destroyed and re-constructed for the components in the Private module, and I understand that it is exactly what is supposed to happen under the current route configuration.

I want -

1. the Public module to be loaded normally(eagerly)
2. the Private module to be loaded lazily
3. the `MainShellComponent` not to be destroyed and re-constructed

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave everything as a child of the shell component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MainShellComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
            { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'home', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'user', loadChildren: './private/private.module#PrivateModule' },
            { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
        ]
    }
];
```